# org.ofbiz.base.util.UtilMisc "error"

Tags: ofbiz

I got a problem with a function of ofbiz, which I can't explain:

The following code is marked with an error (in eclipse):

UtilMisc = org.ofbiz.base.util.UtilMisc

> The method toList(T, T, T, T, T, T) in the type UtilMisc is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 
>        Object)

```
List fieldValues = UtilMisc.toList(
                            dataObj.get("object_name"),
                            dataObj.get("mte_name"),
                            dataObj.get("system_id"),
                            dataObj.get("sap_ref"),
                            dataObj.get("limit_1"),
                            dataObj.get("limit_2"),
                            dataObj.get("editable"),
                            dataObj.get("id"));
```

If I remove two objects (does not matter which one), the error is gone.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong here?

Regards
LStrike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

http://opensourcejavaphp.net/java/ofbiz/org/ofbiz/base/util/UtilMisc.java.html

You can pass at maximum six single objects or a collection.
So I made two lists and concatenated them.

```
List fieldValues = UtilMisc.toList(
                            dataObj.get("object_name"),
                            dataObj.get("mte_name"),
                            dataObj.get("system_id"),
                            dataObj.get("sap_ref"), 
                            dataObj.get("limit_1"),
                            dataObj.get("limit_2"));

                    List fieldValues2 = UtilMisc.toList(
                            dataObj.get("editable"), 
                            dataObj.get("id"));

                    fieldValues.addAll(fieldValues2);
```